# can someone explain me this code in java?

Tags: java

```
public class Training {

    public static void main(String[] args)

   {

        System.out.println(Numbers(3200));

    }

    private static int Numbers(int value)

    {

        if(value < 0)

        {return -1;}

        int result = 0;

        while (value >0)

        {

            int digit = value % 10;

            result += digit;

            value /= 10;

        }

        return result;

    }
}
```

i would like if someone would explain me what the code in the while loop does because i cannot understand it. i only need the explanation of that one codeblock. specifically speaking of this:

```
while (value >0)

        {

            int digit = value % 10;

            result += digit;

            value /= 10;

        }
```

Comment: Do you know what `%` does?  This is called the modulo operator, if you need to look it up.  What this loop does is add up all the digits in a number and put it in the `result` variable.  For example if `value` is `123`, `result` will be `6`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find the explanation of each line in while loop.

```
while (value >0)

    {

        int digit = value % 10; // this will assign digit with last digit 
                                // from the parameter number . 
                                //In this case 3200 - last digit is 0. % is modulo operation. 
                                //Since it is a loop in every iteration it will 
                                //fetch each digit from the right

        result += digit;    //This will add each of the digit with the result 
                            //which is 0 before the iterations starts. 
                            //ie 0+0+2+3 = 5(after all the iteration)

        value /= 10;        //Resetting value to 320 in first iteration
                            //32 in second iteration and 
                            // 3 in third iteration 
                            // in 4th iteration this will be 0.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

`value % 10` => This is the modulo of the scale division of `value` and `10`, which means that digit is the remainder from the division algorithm.

Example : `5 % 2` will return `1` because `5 / 2 = 2 remainder 1`

`result += digit` means `result = result + digit;`

`value /= 10` means `value = value / 10;`